# Will there be a Java Tridion Reference Implementation?

Tags: dxa

When the DD4T Java version is released, will there be a Java version of the STRI?

Comment: +1. Chris asks a good TRex question especially since TRI encourages questions about it here and I've heard a few wondering the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there will be.

We had a lot of work putting this one together (more than initially expected, and more than we needed for .NET) and actually there's already a lot of that work surfacing in the [DD4T 2.0 project](http://blog.trivident.com/2014/12/introducing-dd4t-version-2-0-for-java/).

Right now we're at a stage where we're nearly dev complete, but QA and Documentation is still missing. I am aiming (hoping?) for an April/May release.

Comment: Two identical answers, so the one accepted will prove who of us is more popular ;o)

Comment: :) and the other one will then delete his answer

Comment: Okay, that is a deal ;o)

Comment: Actually, keeping 2 answers is better for site statistics :D, but I'll gladly delete mine if yours is chosen. We are putting heaps of pressure on Chris now...

Comment: Ahah. Yeah, no worries, both answers are correct, he can flip a coin on it

Comment: If you're badge hunting, you should wait for downvotes before deleting

Answer (score 8):

Yes there will be a Java version of STRI, we actually have written all (or maybe I should be safe and say most) of the code already.

But there are a few things holding us back from releasing it to the community at this point. It is not waiting for DD4T 2.0 to be released, but we will try to include DD4T 2.0 if that comes out before we can release.

As soon as the hurdles are taken there will be a Java version, which is architecturally similar to the .NET release.

Comment: Nice multi-threading here :)